# I'm new on React.js, what this error mean? (Pusher variable initiation)

Tags: reactjs, pusher

lately I've worked on some React and Pusher app, I tried to recreate a video call app with some React's library called "simple-peer" by following this source code [AfikDeri/laravel-react-webrtc-video-chat](https://github.com/AfikDeri/laravel-react-webrtc-video-chat).

fast forward, I apparently found the problem by comparing the worked one, I found that there's is something weird with Pusher's variable initialization. I'm really new on React.js and need your kind explanation about this. thanks.

**- the console.log result (left working one, right error)**
[image: console.log (left working one, right error)]

**- Page_VideoCall.js**

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
import { ChatFeed, Message } from "react-chat-ui";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import Cookies from "js-cookie";
import { cl, getAuthToken, getCurrentUser, getGlobalVar } from "../utils";
import Parser from "html-react-parser";

// video call 
import MediaHandler from "./MediaHandler";
import Pusher from "pusher-js";
import Peer from "simple-peer";
const APP_KEY = "xx";

export class Page_VideoCall extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        // init var
        this.state = {
            auth_token: getAuthToken(),
            config: getGlobalVar(),
            response_message: "",
            messages: [],
            chat_info: "",
            material: "",
            exam: "",
            member: "",

            onplay: false,

            hasMedia: false,
            otherUserId: null
        };

        this.user = {
            // id: getCurrentUser().user_id,
            id: getCurrentUser().user_id,
            name: getCurrentUser().nama
        };
        this.user.stream = null;
        this.peers = {};

        this.mediaHandler = new MediaHandler();
        this.setupPusher();

        this.callTo = this.callTo.bind(this);
        this.setupPusher = this.setupPusher.bind(this);
        this.startPeer = this.startPeer.bind(this);
    }

    /*
     * THIS ALREADY WORKIN
     */
    componentDidMount() {
        // get params from url
        const { chat_is_group } = this.props.match.params;
        const { chat_id } = this.props.match.params;

        // get from database
        // do request
        // chat is group / chat_id
        axios({
            method: "get",
            url: `${this.state.config.API_ENDPOINT}/chat-detail/${chat_is_group}/${chat_id}`,
            headers: {
                Authorization: this.state.auth_token
            }
        })
            .then(response => {
                // if not success
                if (response.data.success == false) {
                    // show error
                    this.setState({
                        response_message: `<div className="alert alert-danger">${response.data.message}</div>`
                    });
                } else {
                    // cl("data = ");
                    // cl(response.data.data.chat_info);

                    // success data
                    this.setState({
                        chat_info: response.data.data.chat_info
                    });

                    // start
                    console.log("mounting...");

                    this.mediaHandler.getPermissions().then(stream => {
                        this.setState({
                            hasMedia: true
                        });
                        this.user.stream = stream;

                        try {
                            this.myVideo.srcObject = stream;
                        } catch (e) {
                            this.myVideo.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                        }

                        // display my camera
                        cl("display my camera view.... ");
                        this.myVideo.play();
                    });
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                // Do something with response error
                if (error.message === "Network Error") {
                    this.setState({
                        response_message: `<div className="alert alert-danger">Tidak dapat menyambung ke internet, periksa koneksi anda.</div>`
                    });
                } else {
                    // others error
                    this.setState({
                        response_message: `<div className="alert alert-danger">${error}</div>`
                    });
                }
            })
            .then(function() {
                // always executed
            });

        //vc
    }

    setupPusher() {
        Pusher.logToConsole = true;
        // console.log("do pusher auth...");
        console.log("%c setupPusher() ", "background: #222; color: #bada55");

        this.pusher = new Pusher(APP_KEY, {
            authEndpoint: `${this.state.config.API_ENDPOINT}/pusher/auth`,
            cluster: "ap1",
            auth: {
                params: this.user.id,
                headers: {
                    "X-CSRF-Token": window.csrfToken,
                    auth_token: this.state.auth_token
                }
            }
        });

        console.log("%c this.pusher=", "background: #222; color: #bada55");
        console.log(this.pusher , "background: #222; color: #bada55");

        cl("subscribe to video channel...");
        this.channel = this.pusher.subscribe("presence-video-channel");
        console.log(this.channel);

        // cl
        cl("send signal to : " + this.user.id);
        this.channel.bind(`client-signal-${this.user.id}`, signal => {
            let peer = this.peers[signal.userId];

            // if peer is not already exists, we got an incoming call
            if (peer === undefined) {
                this.setState({ otherUserId: signal.userId });
                this.peer = this.startPeer(signal.userId, false);
            }

            this.peer.signal(signal.data);

            // signal data
            cl("signal.data = ");
            cl(signal.data);

            // signal data
            cl("peer = ");
            cl(this.peer);

            // c
            console.log("incoming signal...");
        });
    }

    startPeer(userId, initiator = true) {
        // mulai peer connection
        console.log("%c startPeer() ", "background: #222; color: #bada55");

        this.peer = new Peer({
            initiator,
            stream: this.user.stream,
            trickle: false
        });

        this.peer.on("signal", data => {
            console.log(
                "%c peer.on(data) ",
                "background: #222; color: #bada55"
            );
            cl("userId=");
            cl(userId);

            this.channel.trigger(`client-signal-${userId}`, {
                type: "signal",
                userId: this.user.id,
                data: data
            });

            // rev
            console.log("kirim sinyal ke: " + userId);
            console.log("this.user.id = " + this.user.id);
            console.log("this.user = ");
            console.log(this.user);
            console.log("userId = " + userId);
        });

        this.peer.on("stream", stream => {
            console.log(
                "%c peer.on(stream) ",
                "background: #222; color: #bada55"
            );
            cl("peer=");
            cl(this.peer);

            try {
                this.userVideo.srcObject = stream;
            } catch (e) {
                this.userVideo.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
            }

            this.userVideo.play();

            // rev
            console.log("play stream from: " + userId);
        });

        this.peer.on("close", () => {
            console.log(
                "%c peer.on(close) ",
                "background: #222; color: #bada55"
            );
            cl("peer=");
            cl(this.peer);

            cl("konseksi peer ditutup: " + userId);

            let peer = this.peers[userId];
            if (peer !== undefined) {
                peer.destroy();
            }

            this.peers[userId] = undefined;
        });

        return this.peer;
    }

    callTo(userId) {
        console.log("lakukan call ke: " + userId);

        this.peers[userId] = this.startPeer(userId);
    }

    render() {
        const chat_info2 = this.state.chat_info;

        // make some information differences
        // if (chat_info.chat_is_group == 1) {
        if (1 == 1) {
            return (
                // Your JSX...

                // <div className="card-body msg_card_body">
                //     <Link
                //         className="btn btn-primary"
                //         to={`/material/${chat_info.chat_is_group}/${chat_info.chat_id}`}
                //     >
                //         <span className="fa fa-paperclip"></span> Materi
                //     </Link>

                //     <Link
                //         className="btn btn-primary"
                //         to={`/material/${chat_info.chat_is_group}/${chat_info.chat_id}`}
                //     >
                //         <span className="fa fa-paperclip"></span> Materi
                //     </Link>
                // </div>

                <div className="chat-detail card">
                    <div className="vc">
                        <div className="video-container">
                            <div className="button-top">
                                <Link className="btn-child" to="/messages">
                                    <div className="fas fa-arrow-left"></div>
                                </Link>
                                <div className="btn-child pull-right">
                                    {chat_info2.chat_title}
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div className="video-a">
                                <div className="preload">
                                    <img
                                        src={`${process.env.MIX_REACT_PUBLIC_URL}img/preload.gif`}
                                    ></img>
                                </div>
                                <video
                                    className="my-video"
                                    ref={(ref) => {
                                        this.myVideo = ref;
                                    }}
                                ></video>
                            </div>
                            <div className="video-b">
                                <div className="preload">
                                    <img
                                        src={`${process.env.MIX_REACT_PUBLIC_URL}img/preload.gif`}
                                    ></img>
                                </div>
                                <video
                                    className="user-video"
                                    ref={(ref) => {
                                        this.userVideo = ref;
                                    }}
                                ></video>
                            </div>

                            <div className="button">
                                {[1, 2].map(userId => {
                                    return this.user.id !== userId ? (
                                        <button
                                            key={userId}
                                            onClick={() => this.callTo(userId)}
                                        >
                                            Call {userId}
                                        </button>
                                    ) : null;
                                })}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
}

export default Page_VideoCall;
``
```

Comment: Please remember that there are guidelines for posting to Stackoverflow: specifically please read through ["how to ask a good question"](/help/how-to-ask) and then edit your question, and take some time to form a [mcve]: not all your code is even remotely related to this problem, and not all of your log matters: remove the parts that don't contribute to showing off the problem you're facing. Taking a bit more time to ask a good question means it will take _less_ time to get a good answer.

Comment: Also note that your screenshot does not show any errors at all. It _does_ show warnings, and they're very true: **never use document.write** - we've had the console API for a decade now, and DOM functions for far longer than that. Whatever you're using `document.write` for, [that is not what you should be using to do that](http://pomax.github.io/1473270609919/if-you-use-use-document-write-you-suck-at-javascript)

Comment: it's not showing any error, because the context I asked it's not about the error but about console result meaning. thanks

Comment: Exactly, so please read ["how to ask a good question"](/help/how-to-ask) and update your post and the images/code you show to help explain the core problem.

Comment: Please do not use images to convey important textual information for the question - it makes it impossible to search for and very hard for people with reduced eyesight to make any sense of the question.